# Proving Lindelof hypothesis using Phragmen-Lindelof theorem and Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Apparently, assuming the Riemann Hypothesis to be true, we could use  Phragmen-Lindelof theorem to deduce the Lindelof Hypothesis. I searched for a while but could not find a proof. Could anyone share a reference for such a proof?

Here is the statement of the theorem.

**Phragmen-Lindelof theorem.** $s=\sigma +it$. Suppose $f(s)$ is holomorphic in the strip $\sigma_1 \leq \sigma \leq \sigma_2$, except for finitely many singularities, and for all $\epsilon>0$,
$$
f(\sigma+it) = O( e^{e^{\epsilon |t|}}), t\to \infty.
$$
If $f(\sigma_k+it) = O(|t|^{r_k})$ for $k=1,2$, then
$$
f(s)=O(|t|^{r(\sigma)}),
$$
where $r(\sigma)$ is the function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ of which the graph is a straight line connecting the two points $(\sigma_k,r_k),k=1,2$.

Comment: this is a standard result that holds for any $L$ functions under the GRH for the respective $L$ and it is an easy consequence of the holomorphicity of $\log \zeta$ in the half-plane $1/2 < \sigma$ and the three-circle theorem; actually much more can be said as there is an equivalence between Lindelof and an $o(\log T)$ bound of zeroes with ordinates between $T$ and $T+1$ and real part greater than $1/2$ which is called Backlund theorem in the RZ case - see this paper (or any standard boook on RZ like Titchmarsh, Edward) for details https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aspm/1548550895

Comment: There is a also description of how to prove this in Iwaniec and Kowalski's book.